# SQL How to get and use previous data and calculate later

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

This is data I have:

```
+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+
| id  |    date     |  status  |  health   |
+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:00 | STARTING | UNHEALTHY |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:03 | ACTIVE   | UNHEALTHY |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:05 | ACTIVE   | UNHEALTHY |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:08 | ACTIVE   | HEALTHY   |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:14 | ACTIVE   | UNHEALTHY |
+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

And I want to calculate downtime caused by STARTING (in this example, start from 4/5/20 3:03 ~ 4/5/20 3:08).

This is the result I was hoping for:

```
+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| id  |    date     |  status  |  health   | STARTING_CAUSED_DOWNTIME_IN_SECONDS |
+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:00 | STARTING | UNHEALTHY |                                     |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:03 | ACTIVE   | UNHEALTHY |                                     |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:05 | ACTIVE   | UNHEALTHY |                                     |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:08 | ACTIVE   | HEALTHY   |                                 480 |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:14 | ACTIVE   | UNHEALTHY |                                     |
+-----+-------------+----------+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

If you see this, I didn't consider last row, ACTIVE / UNHEALTHY (3:14) because it's not STARTING caused downtime (which means UNHEALTHY right after STARTING)

What I've tried:

```
SELECT 
id,date,status,prev_status,health,prev_health,LAST_START_TIME,HEALTHY_AFTER_STARTING_TIME
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
        id,date,status,health,
        LAG(status) OVER(partition BY id ORDER BY DATE) AS prev_status,
        LAG(health) OVER (partition BY id ORDER BY DATE) AS prev_health,
        (case when status = 'ACTIVE' AND prev_status = 'STARTING' then date end) AS LAST_START_TIME,
        (case when status = 'ACTIVE' AND prev_status = 'ACTIVE' AND prev_health = 'UNAVAILABLE' AND health_state <> 'UNAVAILABLE' THEN date END) AS HEALTHY_AFTER_STARTING_TIME
        FROM  
        DB_TABLE_04
    ) t1 ORDER BY DATE
```

I tried to find 2 time (when the STARTING downtime starts / when STARTING downtime ends) by using this query.

2 problems I found.

1. When I find the second time, when STARTING downtime ends (HEALTHY_AFTER_STARTING_TIME), I wasn't able to figure out how to do find downtime duration.

I think it needs to be something similar to:

```
(extract(epoch from (starting_downtime_end - most_recent_starting_downtime_start)))
```

but how do I achieve it?

2. This is bigger problem. If I go with this approach, I will end up considering all ACTIVE / UNHEALTHY cases even it's not caused by starting

For example, it will create something like:

```
+-----+-------------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| id  |    date     |  status  | prev_status |  health   | prev_health | LAST_START_TIME | HEALTHY_AFTER_STARTING_TIME |
+-----+-------------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:00 | STARTING |             | UNHEALTHY |             |                 |                             |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:03 | ACTIVE   | STARTING    | UNHEALTHY | UNHEALTHY   | 4/5/20 3:00     |                             |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:05 | ACTIVE   | ACTIVE      | UNHEALTHY | UNHEALTHY   |                 |                             |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:08 | ACTIVE   | ACTIVE      | HEALTHY   | UNHEALTHY   |                 | 4/5/20 3:08                 |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:14 | ACTIVE   | ACTIVE      | UNHEALTHY | HEALTHY     |                 |                             |
| 270 | 4/5/20 3:18 | ACTIVE   | ACTIVE      | HEALTHY   | UNHEALTHY   |                 | 4/5/20 3:18                 |
+-----+-------------+----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+-----------------+-----------------------------+
```

I don't want consider 4/5/20 3:18 case, but it will.

How can I achieve from the data what I have to the result I want?

Can I also use window function in this problem as well?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I started learning sql as sql-server, but currently working on redshift. That's why I added both. I will keep it to the one I'm currently working on from now on.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . This would seem to get the date that you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when health = 'HEALTHY'
             then max(case when status = 'STARTING' then date end) over
                      (partition by id
                       order by date
                       rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                      )
        end) as starting_date
from DB_TABLE_04 t;
```

And the difference in seconds:

```
datediff(second,
         (case when health = 'HEALTHY'
               then max(case when status = 'STARTING' then date end) over
                        (partition by id
                         order by date
                         rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                        )
          end),
         date
        ) as seconds_diff
```

Also, the window frame clause (`rows between`) is unnecessary in SQL Server but required in Redshift.

Comment: Thanks, I almost got to here too, but with this approach, 2nd problem I concerned is still showing up in the result. I only want to show the result number ONCE when it becomes ACTIVE   | UNHEALTHY to ACTIVE   | HEALTHY for every STARTING status. With this approach, number will show up for both 4/5/20 3:08 AND 4/5/20 3:18 cases from my last example, and I don't want 4/5/20 3:18  one to show up. Is there a trick to modify from what you have now to what I want? Feel like it's almost there but I'm stuck here

Comment: with this approach starting_date will keep show up and only change it's date when new starting event happens, and this will try to datediff every time when there's HEALTHY health, what I want is downtime caused STARTING. Little bit different